# override copy method to increment sequence number

Tags: methods, overriding, odoo, sequence

I'm trying to override create and copy methods so that whenever i execute any of this methods my sequence number auto-increment, here is the create method:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    data_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    sequence_ids = data_obj.search(cr, uid, [('name','=','seq_tour_booking')], context=context)
    sequence_id = data_obj.browse(cr, uid, sequence_ids[0], context=context).res_id
    if vals.get('name','/') =='/':
        code = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get_id(cr, uid, sequence_id, 'id', context) or '/'
        vals['name'] = code
    return super(tour_booking, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

any ideas for the copy method?
thank you.

Comment: You don't need to override 'copy' method because it calls 'create' method internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked :

```
def copy(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
    if default == None:
        default = {}
    default['name'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid,'your.object.name')
    return super(your_class_name, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context=context)
```

Answer (score 1):

MAybe I'm wrong, but you shouldn't need to override also **copy** because it calls **create**: thus overriding it should be enough.

Comment: You are right, no need to override copy method, because it calls create internally.

Comment: Alessandro thank you for your answer but i already tried that and it's not working , i checked the copy method and it's not working like that , it calls create but some lines need to be added.

Comment: Ok, so you did find a solution? Could you please post it in order to help others with the same issue?